# "Operation now in progress" exception when connecting bluetooth client to server with pybluez

Tags: python, bluetooth, rfcomm, pybluez

I took the [rfcomm-server.py](https://github.com/pybluez/pybluez/blob/master/examples/simple/rfcomm-server.py) and [rfcomm-client.py](https://github.com/pybluez/pybluez/blob/master/examples/simple/rfcomm-client.py) from the PyBluez repository on github. The contents of these scripts is the following:

rfcomm-server.py:

```
import bluetooth

server_sock = bluetooth.BluetoothSocket(bluetooth.RFCOMM)
server_sock.bind(("", bluetooth.PORT_ANY))
server_sock.listen(1)

port = server_sock.getsockname()[1]

uuid = "94f39d29-7d6d-437d-973b-fba39e49d4ee"

bluetooth.advertise_service(server_sock, "SampleServer", service_id=uuid,
                            service_classes=[uuid, bluetooth.SERIAL_PORT_CLASS],
                            profiles=[bluetooth.SERIAL_PORT_PROFILE],
                            # protocols=[bluetooth.OBEX_UUID]
                            )

print("Waiting for connection on RFCOMM channel", port)

client_sock, client_info = server_sock.accept()
print("Accepted connection from", client_info)

try:
    while True:
        data = client_sock.recv(1024)
        if not data:
            break
        print("Received", data)
except OSError:
    pass

print("Disconnected.")

client_sock.close()
server_sock.close()
print("All done.")
```

rfcomm-client.py:

```
import sys
import bluetooth


addr = None

if len(sys.argv) < 2:
    print("No device specified. Searching all nearby bluetooth devices for "
          "the SampleServer service...")
else:
    addr = sys.argv[1]
    print("Searching for SampleServer on {}...".format(addr))

# search for the SampleServer service
uuid = "94f39d29-7d6d-437d-973b-fba39e49d4ee"
service_matches = bluetooth.find_service(uuid=uuid, address=addr)

if len(service_matches) == 0:
    print("Couldn't find the SampleServer service.")
    sys.exit(0)

first_match = service_matches[0]
port = first_match["port"]
name = first_match["name"]
host = first_match["host"]

print("Connecting to \"{}\" on {}".format(name, host))

# Create the client socket
sock = bluetooth.BluetoothSocket(bluetooth.RFCOMM)
sock.connect((host, port))

print("Connected. Type something...")
while True:
    data = input()
    if not data:
        break
    sock.send(data)

sock.close()
```

I first startup the server script which outputs "Waiting for connection on RFCOMM channel 1" and then block waiting for incoming connections. Then I run the client script with the argument 'localhost'. When I do this the SampleServer is found, but when the script tries to connect it blocks for a few second and then raises "bluetooth.btcommon.BluetoothError: [Errno 115] Operation now in progress". If I then try again I get the exception: "bluetooth.btcommon.BluetoothError: [Errno 16] Device or resource busy". The full output is:

```
$> ./client.c localhost
Searching for SampleServer on localhost...
Connecting to "SampleServer" on localhost
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 3, in connect
_bluetooth.error: (115, 'Operation now in progress')

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/test/./client.py", line 42, in <module>
    sock.connect((host, port))
  File "<string>", line 5, in connect
bluetooth.btcommon.BluetoothError: [Errno 115] Operation now in progress
$> ./client.c localhost
Searching for SampleServer on localhost...
Connecting to "SampleServer" on localhost
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 3, in connect
_bluetooth.error: (16, 'Device or resource busy')

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/test/./client.py", line 42, in <module>
    sock.connect((host, port))
  File "<string>", line 5, in connect
bluetooth.btcommon.BluetoothError: [Errno 16] Device or resource busy
```

One point which may be notable. When I leave out the localhost argument from the client. It won't find the SampleServer, which is odd because in that case it should be scanning all devices including localhost.

I have tried setting the host and port number manually in the connect call of client. I have tried changing the uuid of the server. Both of which didn't make a difference.

Comment: Are you running both scripts on the same pc?

Comment: Yes, but I looked it up. That should work.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how this script works, but I believe sending and receiving Bluetooth on the same adapter does not work. Might be wrong though